# Is the Azure Storage SDK for Java V8 the latest version to work with Table Storage?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

We are using the Azure Storage SDK for Java V8 in an application to access a simple table in a storage account with few lines, this version is failing the customer security scan, but the new version of the SDK doesn't seems to work with table storage, checking the documentation, it appears that the only way to use a table storage with the newest SDK is accessing through the Cosmos DB Table API.

The Azur Storage for Java SDK page (https://github.com/azure/azure-storage-java) shows only Blob and Queue components. The Azure documentation is not clear on this but all samples point to V8 (or older) SDKs, like this sample  https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-table-java-getting-started

Is there any way to access a table storage in Java without using the Cosmos DB Table API or the outdated V8 SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, Azure Tables And any client libraries for Table have actually moved over to the CosmosDB team ,and there are no plans to support them.

And about the table support [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java/issues/393) in the github has been closed.

So if you want to use Table SDK with Java, you have to use the legacy SDK. Now you could only get the latest SDK for table is CosmosDB.

Hope this could help you, if you still have other questions,please let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I just needed to be absolutely sure.

Comment: @Alex Nobre, if this could help you, you could mark it as the answer.Thanks!